# Is there a way to list names of folders in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

Suppose I have folders '/1234' '/2345' and '/3456' in storage. Is there a way to list out all of the names of the folders? The bigger problem I'm trying to do is match an input with a folder name and then access the contents of the folder, so if there's an easier way, let me know.

Tried using listAll, but don't think that works

Comment: I am not a firebase expert, but a cursory google search does indicate that `listAll` is probably what you're looking for.  Can you give some more details on what you've tried, besides "I don't think it works"?

Comment: This specific sample looks pretty good: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files. If you tried that, but it didn't work - can you edit your question to show what you tried? Following the recipe in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) probably goes a long way to us being able to help.